# Implement listener for onClick of a checkbox in activity from an adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener

I need to create an interface for checkbox clickListener in an adapter so i can implement it in a fragment.

The code below is in myadapter, i need to move the logic inside the clickListener in a Fragment that uses the adapter

```
holder.ivLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!isLike) {
            like(postsData.getNews_id());
            realmResults.get(position).setChecked(true);
            holder.tvNewsCountLike.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(holder.tvNewsCountLike.getText().toString()) + 1));
            holder.ivLike.setChecked(true);
            isLike = true;
        } else {
            unlike(postsData.getNews_id());
            holder.tvNewsCountLike.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(holder.tvNewsCountLike.getText().toString()) - 1));
            holder.ivLike.setChecked(false);
            isLike = false;

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: use an interface to do that

Comment: I don't how to do that, can you help out please

Comment: `EventBus` is another option which may be simpler to implement

Comment: @PPartisan i don't think i need to add another library before i can do this, the logic is what am missing. I will glad if you can help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interface callback here.

Ex:

```
public class MyAdapter {
private MyListener mListener;


public void setListener(MyListener listener){
  mListene r= listener;
}


 //where ever you want to call back
 if(mListener != null){
  mListener.onNotify();
}

public interface MyListener{
 void onNotify();
}

}
```

Activity/ Fargment

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyAdapter.MyListener{

    myAdapter.setListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onNotify(){
      //do your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, however on scroll the checkbox automatically deselect, how can i handle that.

Comment: You have to have a boolean on your model class which can hold the status of your check box.

Answer (score 2):

In your adapter, declare something like this as your `Listener` interface:

```
public class FooAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    public interface Listener {
        void onItemClicked(); // Customize to your needs
    }

    private final List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addListener(Listener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    // In your viewholder:
    holder.ivLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            for(Listener l : listeners) l.onItemClicked();
        }
    });
}
```

Now, in your fragment, implement the listener and listen to the adapter:

```
public class FooFragment extends Fragment implements FooAdapter.Listener {

    // In onCreate()
        ...
        FooAdapter adapter = new FooAdapter();
        adapter.addListener(this);
        ...

    @Override public void onItemClicked() {
        // Add your logic here.
    }
}
```